# Rotar imagen con clase Graphics

Tags: java

Tengo un pequeño problema con mi código, que tiene que ver con la clase Graphics. Necesito dibujar un robot y después de eso debo rotarlo la cantidad de grados establecidos. He probado con AffineTransform.getRotateInstance(rotate, centerx, centery), pero no he podido llamar a todas las figuras en conjunto (que están en una clase llamada Figure) para poderlas rotar, necesito llamar esa clase (Figure) en JPanelWorkArea para hacer girar el robot, por favor si alguien puede ayudarme, estaría muy agradecido. Clase Figure:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;


public class Figure {


private Graphics2D graphics2D;
private int size;
private Point point;
private double rotate;

/**
 * Constructor encargado de asignarle un valor al tamaño y coordenadas del robot
 * 
 * @param size
 *            Tamaño de la figura
 * @param point
 *            Coordenada de la figura
 */

public Figure(int size, Point point, double rotate) {
    this.size = size;
    this.point = point;
    this.rotate = rotate;
}

/**
 * Asigna un determinado grafico para la construccion del robot
 * 
 * @param graphics2D
 *            Grafico asignado
 */

public void setGraphics(Graphics2D graphics2D) {
    this.graphics2D = graphics2D;
}

public Graphics2D getGraphics() {
    return this.graphics2D;
}

/**
 * Encargado de construir el sombrero del robot mediante un triangulo, con ayuda
 * del poligono
 */

private void hat() {
    int[] hatX1 = { this.point.x + this.size / 2, this.point.x, this.point.x + this.size };
    int[] hatY1 = { this.point.y - this.size * 7 / 8, this.point.y, this.point.y };

    graphics2D.setColor(new Color(219, 32, 32));
    graphics2D.fillPolygon(hatX1, hatY1, 3);
}

/**
 * Encargado de construir la cara del robot, con ayuda de un cuadrado
 */

private void face() {
    graphics2D.setColor(new Color(113, 126, 140));
    graphics2D.fillRect(this.point.x, this.point.y, this.size, this.size);
}

/**
 * Encargado de construir las orejas del robot, con ayuda de arcos
 */

private void ears() {
    graphics2D.setColor(new Color(252, 88, 93));
    graphics2D.fillArc(this.point.x - this.size / 4, this.point.y + this.size / 4, this.size / 2, this.size / 4, 90,
            180);
    graphics2D.fillArc(this.point.x + this.size * 3 / 4, this.point.y + this.size / 4, this.size / 2, this.size / 4,
            90, -180);
}

/**
 * Encargado de construir los ojos del robot, a partir de cuadrados, y poligonos
 * de rombos para las pupilas
 */

private void eyes() {
    int[] eye1X = { this.point.x + this.size / 4, (int) (this.point.x + this.size * 1.5 / 8),
            this.point.x + this.size / 4, (int) (this.point.x + this.size * 2.5 / 8) };
    int[] eye1Y = { (int) (this.point.y + this.size * 2.5 / 8), this.point.y + this.size * 3 / 8,
            (int) (this.point.y + this.size * 3.5 / 8), this.point.y + this.size * 3 / 8 };
    int[] eye2X = { this.point.x + this.size * 3 / 4, (int) (this.point.x + this.size * 5.5 / 8),
            this.point.x + this.size * 3 / 4, (int) (this.point.x + this.size * 6.5 / 8) };
    int[] eye2Y = { (int) (this.point.y + this.size * 2.5 / 8), this.point.y + this.size * 3 / 8,
            (int) (this.point.y + this.size * 3.5 / 8), this.point.y + this.size * 3 / 8 };

    graphics2D.setColor(new Color(211, 211, 211));
    graphics2D.fillRect(this.point.x + this.size / 8, this.point.y + this.size / 4, this.size / 4, this.size / 4);
    graphics2D.fillRect(this.point.x + this.size * 5 / 8, this.point.y + this.size / 4, this.size / 4, this.size / 4);
    graphics2D.setColor(new Color(0, 0, 0));
    graphics2D.fillPolygon(eye1X, eye1Y, 4);
    graphics2D.fillPolygon(eye2X, eye2Y, 4);
}

/**
 * Encargado de construir la boca del robot mediante un rectangulo, y una linea
 * para los dientes
 */

private void mouth() {
    graphics2D.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    graphics2D.fillRect(this.point.x + this.size / 8, this.point.y + this.size * 5 / 8, this.size * 3 / 4,
            this.size / 4);
    graphics2D.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    graphics2D.drawLine(this.point.x + this.size / 8, this.point.y + this.size * 3 / 4,
            this.point.x + this.size * 7 / 8, this.point.y + this.size * 3 / 4);
}

/**
 * Encargado de construir la columna del robot, a traves de un rectangulo
 */

private void column() {
    graphics2D.setColor(new Color(111, 111, 111));
    graphics2D.fillRect(this.point.x + this.size * 3 / 8, this.point.y + this.size, this.size / 4,
            this.size * 11 / 4);
}

/**
 * Encargado de construir el tronco del robot, junto con un cajon, con ayuda de
 * cuadrados
 */

private void trunk() {
    graphics2D.setColor(new Color(113, 126, 140));
    graphics2D.fillRect(this.point.x - this.size / 8, this.point.y + this.size * 11 / 8, this.size * 5 / 4,
            this.size * 5 / 4);
    graphics2D.setColor(new Color(99, 99, 99));
    graphics2D.drawRect(this.point.x, this.point.y + this.size * 3 / 2, this.size, this.size);
    graphics2D.fillRect((int) (this.point.x + this.size * 0.3 / 8), (int) (this.point.y + this.size * 12.3 / 8),
            (int) (this.size * 7.6 / 8), (int) (this.size * 7.6 / 8));
    graphics2D.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    graphics2D.fillOval((int) (this.point.x + this.size * 6.5 / 8), (int) (this.point.y + this.size * 15.5 / 8),
            this.size / 8, this.size / 8);
}

/**
 * Encargado de construir los hombros del robot con ayuda de rectangulos
 */

private void shoulder() {
    graphics2D.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    graphics2D.fillRect(this.point.x - this.size * 3 / 8, this.point.y + this.size * 3 / 2, this.size / 4,
            this.size * 5 / 8);
    graphics2D.fillRect(this.point.x + this.size * 9 / 8, this.point.y + this.size * 3 / 2, this.size / 4,
            this.size * 5 / 8);
    graphics2D.fillRect(this.point.x - this.size / 2, this.point.y + this.size * 13 / 8, this.size / 8,
            this.size * 3 / 8);
    graphics2D.fillRect((int) (this.point.x + this.size * 11.1 / 8), this.point.y + this.size * 13 / 8, this.size / 8,
            this.size * 3 / 8);
}

/**
 * Encargado de construir los brazos del robot, mediante rectangulos
 */

private void arms() {
    graphics2D.setColor(new Color(113, 126, 140));
    graphics2D.fillRect(this.point.x - this.size * 3 / 4, (int) (this.point.y + this.size * 7 / 4), this.size / 4,
            this.size / 8);
    graphics2D.fillRect(this.point.x + this.size * 3 / 2, (int) (this.point.y + this.size * 7 / 4), this.size / 4,
            this.size / 8);
    graphics2D.fillRect(this.point.x - this.size * 3 / 4, (int) (this.point.y + this.size * 7 / 4), this.size / 8,
            (int) (this.size * 7 / 8));
    graphics2D.fillRect(this.point.x + this.size * 7 / 4, (int) (this.point.y + this.size * 7 / 4), this.size / 8,
            (int) (this.size * 7 / 8));
}

/**
 * Encargado de construir las manos del robot, con ayuda de poligonos
 * irregulares
 */

private void hands() {
    graphics2D.setColor(new Color(35, 92, 132));
    int[] hand1X = { this.point.x - this.size * 3 / 4, this.point.x - this.size * 7 / 8,
            (int) (this.point.x - this.size * 6.5 / 8), this.point.x - this.size * 3 / 4,
            this.point.x - this.size * 5 / 8, (int) (this.point.x - this.size * 4.5 / 8),
            this.point.x - this.size / 2, this.point.x - this.size * 5 / 8 };
    int[] hand1Y = { this.point.y + this.size * 21 / 8, this.point.y + this.size * 11 / 4,
            this.point.y + this.size * 23 / 8, this.point.y + this.size * 11 / 4, this.point.y + this.size * 11 / 4,
            this.point.y + this.size * 23 / 8, this.point.y + this.size * 11 / 4,
            this.point.y + this.size * 21 / 8 };
    int[] hand2X = { this.point.x + this.size * 7 / 4, this.point.x + this.size * 13 / 8,
            (int) (this.point.x + this.size * 13.5 / 8), this.point.x + this.size * 7 / 4,
            this.point.x + this.size * 15 / 8, (int) (this.point.x + this.size * 15.5 / 8),
            this.point.x + this.size * 2, this.point.x + this.size * 15 / 8 };
    int[] hand2Y = { this.point.y + this.size * 21 / 8, this.point.y + this.size * 11 / 4,
            this.point.y + this.size * 23 / 8, this.point.y + this.size * 11 / 4, this.point.y + this.size * 11 / 4,
            this.point.y + this.size * 23 / 8, this.point.y + this.size * 11 / 4,
            this.point.y + this.size * 21 / 8 };

    graphics2D.fillPolygon(hand1X, hand1Y, 8);
    graphics2D.fillPolygon(hand2X, hand2Y, 8);
}

/**
 * Encargado de construir el cinturon del robot, con un rectangulo
 */

private void belt() {
    graphics2D.setColor(new Color(188, 120, 24));
    graphics2D.fillRect(this.point.x, this.point.y + this.size * 21 / 8, this.size, this.size / 4);
}

/**
 * Encargado de construir el soporte del robot, mediante rectangulos
 */

private void support() {
    graphics2D.setColor(new Color(93, 112, 112));
    graphics2D.fillRect(this.point.x - this.size / 4, this.point.y + this.size * 15 / 4, this.size * 3 / 2,
            this.size / 8);
    graphics2D.fillRect(this.point.x, this.point.y + this.size * 29 / 8, this.size, this.size / 8);
    graphics2D.fillRect(this.point.x - this.size / 4, this.point.y + this.size * 15 / 4, this.size / 8,
                this.size / 2);
        graphics2D.fillRect((int) (this.point.x + this.size * 9.1 / 8), this.point.y + this.size * 15 / 4, this.size / 8,
                this.size / 2);
        graphics2D.fillRect(this.point.x, this.point.y + this.size * 29 / 8, this.size / 8, this.size * 3 / 8);
        graphics2D.fillRect((int) (this.point.x + this.size * 7.1 / 8), this.point.y + this.size * 29 / 8, this.size / 8,
                this.size * 3 / 8);
    }

    /**
     * Encargado de construir las ruedas que permiten el movimiento del robot,
     * mediante circulos
     */

    private void wheels() {
        graphics2D.setColor(new Color(0, 0, 0));
        graphics2D.fillOval((int) (this.point.x - this.size * 2.5 / 8), this.point.y + this.size * 17 / 4, this.size / 4,
                this.size / 4);
        graphics2D.fillOval((int) (this.point.x + this.size * 8.6 / 8), this.point.y + this.size * 17 / 4, this.size / 4,
                this.size / 4);
        graphics2D.fillOval((int) (this.point.x - this.size * 0.5 / 8), this.point.y + this.size * 4, this.size / 4,
                this.size / 4);
        graphics2D.fillOval((int) (this.point.x + this.size * 6.5 / 8), this.point.y + this.size * 4, this.size / 4,
                this.size / 4);
    }

    /**
     * Encargado de ensamblar todas las partes del robot, y mostrarlo como una
     * unidad
     */

    public void show() {
        hat();
        face();
        ears();
        eyes();
        mouth();
        column();
        trunk();
        shoulder();
        arms();
        hands();
        belt();
        support();
        wheels();
    }
    }
```

Y esta es la clase JPanelWorkArea:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import javax.swing.JPanel;


public class JPanelWorkArea extends JPanel {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private Figure figure;
    private double centrox = 600;
    private double centroy = 400;
    private double rotate;
    private Point point;
    private int size;

    /**
     * Constructor que le asigna un valor al atributo figure
     * 
     * @param figure
     *            Figura asignada
     */

    public JPanelWorkArea(double rotate, Point p, int size) {
        super();
        this.point = p;
        this.rotate = rotate;
        this.size = size;
    }

    /**
     * Metodo sobreescrito de la clase paint
     * 
     * @param graphics
     */

    @Override

     public void paintComponent(Graphics g){      
            Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g; 

 g2.transform(AffineTransform.getRotateInstance(Math.toRadians(rotate),this.centrox,this.centroy));                     

//          this.repaint();
    }
}
```

Comment: que ocurre cuando haces la rotacion? en que momento dibujas la figura? probaste con `rotate(double theta, double x, double y)`?